# Replace everything inside squared brackets for a particular word

Tags: java, regex

I have the following string (which is on multiple lines):

```
    "locationIds": [
      "london",
      "scotland",
      "wales"
    ],
    "bannerIds": [
      "red banner",
      "blue"
    ],
    "regionIds": [
            
    ],
```

I'm trying to remove everything inside "bannerIds" squared brackets so I am left with a complete string that looks like this:

```
    "locationIds": [
      "london",
      "scotland",
      "wales"
    ],
    "bannerIds": [
      
    ],
    "regionIds": [
            
    ],
```

I've tried doing the following replaceAll using regex but I'm not having any luck with it. (I still get the original bannerIds).

```
string.replaceAll("\"bannerIds\":\[((?s).*[\n\r].*(.*?))\]", "\"bannerIds\": []");
```

How would I do this?

Note:

- The string order may be different (depends on the response and the order we get data back).
- bannerId may not always be there so need to cater for this

Comment: Don't use RegEx to parse JSON. Use a proper parser instead, I'm sure Java can deserialize it pretty nicely

Comment: Exactly. You are processing FORMATTED data, that provides semantic information to you. Dont just ignore that. Parse this as json, and process it accordingly. That might be more expensive, but that is the sane, ROBUST approach.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with Json. You are having trouble with regex, I would like to assist you. You could try following regex.

```
("bannerIds".*?\[)[\s\S]+?(\])
```

Details:

- `("bannerIds".*?\[)`: Group 1 - captures `"bannerIds": [`
- `[\s\S]+?`: matches any whitespace character and any non-whitespace character as few times as possible
- `(\])`: Group 2: captures `]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iRGsjR/1)

I also tried running the code on Java.

```
  String str = "\"locationIds\": [\n"
  + "\t\"london\",\n"
  + "\t\"scotland\",\n"
  + "\t\"wales\"\n"
+"],\n"
+"\"bannerIds\": [\n"
+"\t\"red banner\",\n"
+"\t\"blue\"\n"  
+"],\n"
+"\"regionIds\": [\n"
+"\n"        
+"],\n";

  System.out.println("before replace");
  System.out.println(str);
  String result = str.replaceAll("(\"bannerIds\".*?\\[)[\\s\\S]+?(\\])", "$1$2");
  System.out.println("after replace");

  System.out.println(result);
```

Result:

```
before replace
"locationIds": [
    "london",
    "scotland",
    "wales"
],
"bannerIds": [
    "red banner",
    "blue"
],
"regionIds": [

],

after replace
"locationIds": [
    "london",
    "scotland",
    "wales"
],
"bannerIds": [],
"regionIds": [

],
```